# How can I add additional bundles to a Sapper rollup project

Tags: rollup, svelte, sapper

Probably a little controvertial, but I'd like to be able to bundle additional client-side js within my Sapper project. Currently I've a js folder (static/js) which I'd like to bundle in addition to the svelte src but its a little unclear how the rollup.config is composed and how I'd add this additional entry point.

Currently my rollup.config looks something like this :

```
    import...

    export default{ 
       client: {
          input...
          output...
       },
       server: {
          input...
          output...
       },
       service-worker: {
          input...
          output...
       },
       my-lib: {
          input...
          output...
       }
  }
```

Note; the 'my-lib' part of the config isn't being compiled as you'd imagine.

In comparison, the rollup docs describe the config like the following...

```
  import...

  export default{ 
       input...
       output...
  }
```

The idea here being I'd like to have the application side of things separate from the svelte idiom so I've a little more flexibility to structure my code while leveraging in-browser live code editing and providing other team members a non-svelte entry point.

Additionally, looking at the rollup docs, its more unclear, as the default should export an array. Any help or examples here would be great.

Comment: Did you find a solution?